# CSS conflicting transform properties on same element

Tags: javascript, css, angular, drag-and-drop, translate3d

I am designing a UI that allows the user to drag and drop a box (red outline) to determine its position on the screen (black box).

[UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ksPzE.png)

It can also be moved by changing the inputs on the right.

I am using Angulars cdkDrag for the drag and drop functionality which applies a

```
transform: translate3d(x, y, z)
```

to move the box (i use the event listener to update the input values on the right).

When a user input is applied I update this property depending on the input.

Unfortunately, when the box is dragged again, Angular reapplies a translate3d creating two properties that are conflicting with each other, creating terrible UX when dragging after user input.

[two transform properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7C0r.png)

Is there a way around this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, error messages, markup, and other text **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, there is a way to set the drag position of the element manually. Which in my case I can do on user input.

```
[cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition"

dragPosition = {x: 50, y: 100};
```

This maintains a single translate property and creates a smooth UX